# jquery mobile content vertically centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have several pages (data-role="page"), and each one have a content div (data-role="content"). I simply want to vertically centralise the content div on each page. I tried vertical-align, it didn't work. I tried getting browser height and assign the top, something like this:

```
home_height = $("#home_page_content").height();
            contentTop = (browserHeight - headHeight - home_height)/2;
            $("div:jqmData(role='content')").css("position", "relative").css("top", contentTop);
```

but it didn't work on other pages apart from homepage. Because height() does'n work on invisible elements, the content height will always be 0.

Then I tried a css hacking way to get other content like this:

```
$("#lounge-content").css({
                position:   'absolute',
                visibility: 'hidden',
                display:    'block'
            });
            lounge_height = $("#lounge-content").height();
            $("#lounge-content").css({
                position:   'static', // Again optional if #myDiv is already absolute
                visibility: 'visible'
            });
            loungeTop = (browserHeight - headHeight - lounge_height)/2;
            console.log("lounge height is: " + lounge_height + ", lounge top value now is: " + loungeTop);
            $("#lounge-content").css("position", "relative").css("top", loungeTop);
```

the problem is when I open the file, I can only see the header, content is hidden, I have to refresh the browser to see everything. and it worked fine.

But this apparently is not a very handy way to do it. Maybe vertically centralised a div should never be that difficult? can someone please help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of jQM it can be tricky to find a correct content size, and without it you can't center it verticaly.

**data-role="content"** div height can only be retrieved in pageshow page event. Every other instance will give you content height 0.

I made you a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/JmqX6/

```
$('#index').live('pageshow',function(e,data){    
    $('#index-content').css('margin-top',($(window).height() - $('[data-role=header]').height() - $('[data-role=footer]').height() - $('#index-content').outerHeight())/2);
});
```

Contact me if you need help implementing this in jQM.

### Edit (23.02.2015)

Updated jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/udvhs0Lb/

- live() is not longer available in jQuery (since jQuery 1.8.3 I think) so page even binding should look like this:

  ```
    $(document).on('pageshow','#index', function(e,data){
  ```

Comment: This works when you have only one page, but when you navigate to other pages , ( with proper selector when applied to all the page ) and the page shows,but the page wiggles. Looks pretty bad.

Answer (score 5):

The following works with multiple jQM pages and multiple hidden/shown headers and footers:

```
applyVerticalCentering = function() {
    $(this).on('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){
        $('[data-vertical-centred]').hide();
    });

    $(this).on('pageshow resize',function(e,data){    
        $('[data-vertical-centred]').each(function(index){
            var _this = $(this);
            _this.css('margin-top',
                      ($(window).height() -
                       $('header:visible').height() -
                       $('footer:visible').height() -
                       _this.outerHeight())/2);
            _this.show();
        });
    });
}();
```

Then using declarative style in the html:

```
<div data-role="content" data-vertical-centred>
    hi there in the middle!
    <a href="#page1" data-role="button">clicky</a>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hungrycamel/82KX6/

Comment: this is a great code, I want to add also vertical and horizontal center if you can help me

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers.
For me, the trigger doesn't work, seems due to newer jquery version

```
$('#index').live('pageshow',function(e,data){    
$('#index-content').css('margin-top',($(window).height() - $('[data-role=header]').height() - $('[data-role=footer]').height() - $('#index-content').outerHeight())/2);
});
```

thus, below is the modified code that works for me (which changed only the trigger)

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(event) {
$('#index-content').css('margin-top',($(window).height() - $('[data-role=header]').height() - $('[data-role=footer]').height() - $('#index-content').outerHeight())/2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have to classes to make this.
One for just vertically center something, one for vertically and horizontally:

```
.h-centered-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%)
}

.vh-centered-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

Just apply it to the element you want to center vertically or both